# Visual Studio 2010 and installing a Silverlight gadget

Tags: c#, silverlight

I download the Silverlight gadget extension and create a new project and debug it. It's fine and great, but how can I use this gadget in other projects?
That is, how should I publish a newly created gadget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the Silverlight project, the newly created gadget will be in the "`Project1\SilverlightGadgetDebugger\bin\Debug\Gadgets\SilverlightSidebarGadget\Publish`" directory.
You can install this gadget and show your newly created gadget.